# laravel 5.1 required_without validation

Tags: validation, laravel-5

Using laravel 5.4 I have 2 fields:
kg_bags and g_bags

At least one of them has to have a positive value bigger than Zero.

How do I change the validation required_without to do that?

If I put Zero or -value in one and nothing in the other, I don't get an error, which is wrong.

If I put -1 in kg_bags and nothing in g_bags, I also don't get an error, but the code fails because it cannot use minus values.

My code:

```
 if($request->kg_bags) {
        $this->validate($request,[
            "kg_bags" => "numeric"
        ]);
    }

    if($request->g_bags)
    {
        $this->validate($request,[
            "g_bags" => "numeric"
        ]);
    }

    $this->validate($request,[
        "kg_bags" => "required_without:g_bags",
        "g_bags" => "required_without:kg_bags"
    ],
    [
        'kg_bags.required_without' => 'Please fill in the number of bags you packed',
        'g_bags.required_without' => 'Please fill in the number of bags you packed',
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since -value or zero are not your desired values (only positive), have you consider to add minimum and maximum value to both columns?

Something like

```
$this->validate($request,[
        "kg_bags" => "required_without:g_bags|between:0.00,999.99",
        "g_bags" => "required_without:kg_bags|between:0.00,999.99"
    ],
    [
        'kg_bags.required_without' => 'Please fill in the number of bags you packed',
        'g_bags.required_without' => 'Please fill in the number of bags you packed',
    ]);
```

or

```
if($request->kg_bags) {
        $this->validate($request,[
            "kg_bags" => "numeric|between:0.00,999.99"
        ]);
    }

    if($request->g_bags)
    {
        $this->validate($request,[
            "g_bags" => "numeric|between:0.00,999.99"
        ]);
    }
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thx, but I don't have a max restriction

Comment: I just tried it to see what happens: between:1,999 and I put -1 in kg_bags. Didn't get an error, and my code failed cause it can't use negative value

Comment: Another thing: the min:1 validation works on -1 when I use simple form submission, but when I use ajax, it does not give an error.

Comment: Ok, made it all work, I put the required_without validations before the numeric|min:1 that seems to solve the problem

Comment: Glad to hear that :)